# WhatsApp end-to-end encryption

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, encryption

Earlier this week, I saw below message on WhatsApp

<sub>(Click for larger Variant)</sub>

[image: IMG: Whatsapp End-to-End Encryption]

What does this means to the User?

> *With end-to-end encryption, messages are scrambled as they leave the
>   sender's device and can only be decrypted by the recipient's device.
>   It renders messages unreadable if they are intercepted, for example by
>   criminals.*

**My question is**: Does this end-to-end encryption applies to individual chat and to group chat between **Android-only** devices or it also works on other platforms, Since WhatsApp is available on iOS, Windows Mobile also.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be between all platforms, as its written here:

https://whispersystems.org/blog/whatsapp-complete/

"Over the past year, we've been progressively rolling out Signal Protocol support for all WhatsApp communication across all WhatsApp clients. This includes chats, group chats, attachments, voice notes, and voice calls across Android, iPhone, Windows Phone, Nokia S40, Nokia S60, Blackberry, and BB10."

Comment: is that a official WhatsApp site? I guess we need reliable source to confirm on this Q!

Comment: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/28030015  This may lead a bit further, but still no "they say exactly that" though. But actually for me its quite clear now. Where should be the sense in making this feature platform-depended?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp End-to-End encryption includes chats, group chats, attachments, voice notes, and voice calls across Android, iPhone, Windows Phone, Nokia S40, Nokia S60, Blackberry, and BB10.

The idea of End-to-End encryption is to make a communication more private (like Face-to-Face Conversation) that is when you send a message, the only person who can read it is the person or group chat that you send that message to. None can see that message which includes cybercriminals and hackers. Because the End-to-End Encryption means the content of communications are not stored in plaintext on WhatsApp’s servers. Nor is the company able to decrypt users’ messages to access them since it does not hold the encryption keys. So WhatsApp will be unable to be compelled to hand over messaging data — even if served with a warrant by authorities demanding access.

This is applicable to the Users running the most recent versions of WhatsApp on any platform now get full end to end encryption for every message they send and every WhatsApp call they make when communicating with each other.

Comment: There are other attack types for non-encrypted messages, such as MiTM attacks. Since end-to-end encryption prevents this technique, I think you should mention this in your answer.